# please How to convert mysql query to pdo in my code?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my code PHP in mySQLquery to unique product id function

```
function kode($tabel, $inisial){
$struktur   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabel");
$field      = mysql_field_name($struktur,0);
$panjang    = mysql_field_len($struktur,0);

$qry    = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(".$field.") FROM ".$tabel);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($qry); 
if ($row[0]=="") {
    $angka=0;
}
else {
    $angka      = substr($row[0], strlen($inisial));
}

$angka++;
$angka  =strval($angka); 
$tmp    ="";
for($i=1; $i<=($panjang-strlen($inisial)-strlen($angka)); $i++) {
    $tmp=$tmp."0";  
}
return $inisial.$tmp.$angka; }
```

how to convert this code to php pdo? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard snippet I use for PDO:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxxxxxxx;dbname=streaming", "xxxx", "xxxx");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong', 0, $e);
}


$date = reformatDate($_POST['date']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE date_start = :date";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);

$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This example should point you in the right direction, but you need to do the heavy lifting.

**Update**

This would also be acceptable.

```
$madeupstring = "Mk9285425";
$sql="SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE product = :whatever";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':whatever', $madeupstring);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You could also do this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE product = 'Mk9285425'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, you use the id a date for the product, but what if using string and a number that we set it manually. as an example: MK2300098

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking but I have updated my answer with two more examples that should help you.

Comment: okay. thank you, I understand a little more with your workflow logic, just add the last data retrieval from the field and sorted them back. thanks for the help